# AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.formula.api' has no attribute 'OLS'

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to use Ordinary Least Squares for multivariable regression. But it says that there is no attribute 'OLS' from statsmodels. formula. api library.
I am following the code from a lecture on Udemy
The code is as follows:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
#OrdinaryLeastSquares
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit(
```

The error is as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3bdb0bc861c6> in <module>()
      2 X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
      3 #OrdinaryLeatSquares
----> 4 regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit()

AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.formula.api' has no attribute 'OLS'
```

Comment: you can check the version of `statsmodels`, is it >=  0.5.0? Something like `print (statsmodels.__version__)`

Comment: Use `import statsmodels.api as sm`. The `formula.api` now has only the formula interface to models which are lower case like `ols`

Answer (score 29):

Just for completeness, the code should look like this if statsmodels.**version** is 0.10.0:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
#OrdinaryLeastSquares
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=y, exog=X_opt).fit()
```

Answer (score 16):

Use this import.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

Answer (score 14):

I have tried the above mentioned methods and while

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

the import works for me. When I run the next piece of code

```
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=y, exog=X_opt).fit()
```

it gives me this error.

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''

If you are getting the above mentioned error, you can solve it by specifying `dtype` for the `np.array`.

Replace

```
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

with

```
X_opt = np.array(X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the working solution that I tried today. 
use this in the import

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

and your rest of the fix is mentioned below

```
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
X_opt = X_opt.astype(np.float64)
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(Y, X_opt).fit()
```

This should work because it did work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead, worked for me:

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Josef mentions in the comment, use ols() instead of OLS(), OLS() truly does not exist there.